# Image background does not fill print page fully

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to have a print css style with a background filling all pages. The issue I am having is that the background image only fills as much as there is content so unless the page is perfectly full of content the bottom of the last page will not have a background.

Here is the relevant css:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background-image:url('/sample/img/linedpaper.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:center;
}
@media print{
    body{
        margin: 6mm;
        height:100vh;
    }
    #container{
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0px auto 0 auto;
    }
}
@page {
    margin: 0mm;
    size: A4 portrait;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The worst thing is that it's very difficult to troubleshoot as Chrome print emulation doesn't include page breaks so it looks fine until I print preview.

I tried settings height, min-height to 100% and 100vh on body and html elements with no change. Absolute positioning, margins, padding on the body had no effect either. I am not aware of a way to specifically set the size of an element to the size of a print page. Is there a way?

How can I make the body span the full print page so that the image background also spans the full print page?

Comment: have you tried `background-size:cover`..?

Comment: Are you sure that the background is filling entirely? Try adding `background-size: 100%`

Comment: @Bhuwan I have now, but no change.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb In non-print media yes it fills perfectly. No change with  background-size: 100%.

Comment: Have you tried @Bhuwan's suggestion?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Yes, see above comment.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/8m42qkg6/). See [this](https://imgur.com/5MWxaXZ)

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I tried adding some lorem ipsum text and I do see an issue when content is more than 1 page, take a look: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8m42qkg6/13/)